# No visible @interface for 'UIWebView' declares the selector 'initWithNibName:bundle:'

Tags: interface

First I want to say you that I'm totally new in Xcode so I'm a Newbie.
Then I also want to say you that I'm not able to speak English perfect...I'm learning it.

So, my problem is that I get the following error:

> No visible @interface for 'UIWebView' declares the selector 'initWithNibName:bundle:'

I don't know why, I've already searched in many other forums (and this, too) for this, but the solutions there didn't help me.
I want to create a Table View that loads an UIWebView if I push a row.

That's my Code:

```
    #pragma mark - Table view delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.mehrWebView == nil)
    {
        UIWebView *temp = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyWebView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        self.mehrWebView = temp;
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mehrWebView animated:YES];
}
```

I'm frustrated, I don't know how to continue.
I hope you can help me with my problem.

Thanks & Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `initWithNibName:bundle:` method is an initializer of `UIViewController` classes, not `UIView` classes. On the other hand, `UIWebView` is a `UIView` class, so Xcode correctly tells you that `UIWebView` lacks the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method.

Moreover, you cannot push *views* onto the navigation controller's stack. You need to replace `UIWebView` with the type of the controller of the `@"MyWebView"` nib to make it work.